# How to keep low latency during the preview of video coming from AVFoundation?

Tags: ios, objective-c, avfoundation, video-capture

Apple has a sample code called [Rosy Writer](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/RosyWriter/Introduction/Intro.html) that shows how to capture video and apply effects to it.

During this section of the code, on the `outputPreviewPixelBuffer` part, Apple supposedly shows how they keep preview latency low by dropping stale frames.

```
- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection
{
    CMFormatDescriptionRef formatDescription = CMSampleBufferGetFormatDescription( sampleBuffer );

    if ( connection == _videoConnection )
    {
        if ( self.outputVideoFormatDescription == NULL ) {
            // Don't render the first sample buffer.
            // This gives us one frame interval (33ms at 30fps) for setupVideoPipelineWithInputFormatDescription: to complete.
            // Ideally this would be done asynchronously to ensure frames don't back up on slower devices.
            [self setupVideoPipelineWithInputFormatDescription:formatDescription];
        }
        else {
            [self renderVideoSampleBuffer:sampleBuffer];
        }
    }
    else if ( connection == _audioConnection )
    {
        self.outputAudioFormatDescription = formatDescription;

        @synchronized( self ) {
            if ( _recordingStatus == RosyWriterRecordingStatusRecording ) {
                [_recorder appendAudioSampleBuffer:sampleBuffer];
            }
        }
    }
}

- (void)renderVideoSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer
{
    CVPixelBufferRef renderedPixelBuffer = NULL;
    CMTime timestamp = CMSampleBufferGetPresentationTimeStamp( sampleBuffer );

    [self calculateFramerateAtTimestamp:timestamp];

    // We must not use the GPU while running in the background.
    // setRenderingEnabled: takes the same lock so the caller can guarantee no GPU usage once the setter returns.
    @synchronized( _renderer )
    {
        if ( _renderingEnabled ) {
            CVPixelBufferRef sourcePixelBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer( sampleBuffer );
            renderedPixelBuffer = [_renderer copyRenderedPixelBuffer:sourcePixelBuffer];
        }
        else {
            return;
        }
    }

    if ( renderedPixelBuffer )
    {
        @synchronized( self )
        {
            [self outputPreviewPixelBuffer:renderedPixelBuffer];

            if ( _recordingStatus == RosyWriterRecordingStatusRecording ) {
                [_recorder appendVideoPixelBuffer:renderedPixelBuffer withPresentationTime:timestamp];
            }
        }

        CFRelease( renderedPixelBuffer );
    }
    else
    {
        [self videoPipelineDidRunOutOfBuffers];
    }
}

// call under @synchronized( self )
- (void)outputPreviewPixelBuffer:(CVPixelBufferRef)previewPixelBuffer
{
    // Keep preview latency low by dropping stale frames that have not been picked up by the delegate yet
    // Note that access to currentPreviewPixelBuffer is protected by the @synchronized lock
    self.currentPreviewPixelBuffer = previewPixelBuffer; // A

    [self invokeDelegateCallbackAsync:^{  // B

        CVPixelBufferRef currentPreviewPixelBuffer = NULL; // C
        @synchronized( self ) //D
        {
            currentPreviewPixelBuffer = self.currentPreviewPixelBuffer; // E
            if ( currentPreviewPixelBuffer ) { // F
                CFRetain( currentPreviewPixelBuffer ); // G
                self.currentPreviewPixelBuffer = NULL;  // H
            }
        }

        if ( currentPreviewPixelBuffer ) { // I
            [_delegate capturePipeline:self previewPixelBufferReadyForDisplay:currentPreviewPixelBuffer];  // J
            CFRelease( currentPreviewPixelBuffer );  /K
        }
    }];
}

- (void)invokeDelegateCallbackAsync:(dispatch_block_t)callbackBlock
{
    dispatch_async( _delegateCallbackQueue, ^{
        @autoreleasepool {
            callbackBlock();
        }
    } );
}
```

After hours of trying to understand this code, my brain is smoking and I cannot see how this is done.

Can someone explain like I am 5 years old, OK, make it 3 years old, how is this code doing that?

thanks.

EDIT: I have labeled the lines of `outputPreviewPixelBuffer` with letters to make it easy to understand the order the code is being executed.

So, the method starts and `A` runs and the buffer is stored into the property `self.currentPreviewPixelBuffer`. `B` runs and the local variable `currentPreviewPixelBuffer` is assigned with `NULL`. `D` runs and locks `self`. Then `E` runs and changes the local variable `currentPreviewPixelBuffer` from NULL to the value of `self.currentPreviewPixelBuffer`.

This is the first thing that does not makes sense. Why would I create a variable `currentPreviewPixelBuffer` assign it to `NULL` and on the next line assign it to `self.currentPreviewPixelBuffer`?

The following line is even more insane. Why I am asking if `currentPreviewPixelBuffer` is not `NULL` If I just assigned it to a non `NULL` value on `E`? Then `H` is executed and nulls `self.currentPreviewPixelBuffer`?

One thing I don't get is this: `invokeDelegateCallbackAsync:` is asynchronous, right? if it is asynchronous then every time `outputPreviewPixelBuffer` method runs is to set `self.currentPreviewPixelBuffer = previewPixelBuffer` and dispatch a block for execution, being free to run again.

If `outputPreviewPixelBuffer` is fired faster, we will have a bunch of blocks piled for execution.

Due to the explanations of `Kamil Kocemba`, I undestand that these asynchronous blocks are testing somehow if the previous one finished executing and dropping the frames if not.

Also, what exactly is `@syncronized(self)` locking? Is it preventing `self.currentPreviewPixelBuffer` from being written or read? or is it locking the local variable `currentPreviewPixelBuffer`? If the block under `@syncronized(self)` is synchronous with relation to the scope the line at `I` will never be `NULL` because it is being set on `E`.

Comment: can you share the link to the source code ? Im also interested in learning how to have low latency when editing the sampleBuffers coming from the camera

Comment: the link is on the first paragraph.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank you for highlighting the lines -- this will hopefully make the answer a little bit easier to follow.

Let's go through step by step:

1. `-outputPreviewPixelBuffer:` is called. `self.currentPreviewPixelBuffer` is overwritten *not* in an `@synchronized` block: this means that it is forcibly overwritten, effectively for all threads (I'm glossing over the fact that `currentPreviewPixelBuffer` is `nonatomic`; this is actually unsafe and there is a race here -- you really need it to be `strong, atomic` for this to be really true). If there was a buffer in there, it's now gone the next time a thread is going to go looking for it. This is what the documentation implies -- if there was a value in `self.currentPreviewPixelBuffer` and the delegate has not yet gotten to process the previous value, too bad! It's gone now.
2. The block is sent to the delegate to process asynchronously. In effect, this will likely happen sometime *in the future*, with some indeterminate delay. This means that between when `-outputPreviewPixelBuffer:` is called and when the block is processed, `-outputPreviewPixelBuffer:` can get called again many, many times! This is how the stale frames are dropped -- if it's taking a long time for the delegate to get to processing the block, the latest `self.currentPreviewPixelBuffer` will get overwritten with the latest value again and again, effectively dropping the previous frame.
3. Lines C through H take ownership of `self.currentPreviewPixelBuffer`. You indeed have a local pixel buffer, initially set to `NULL`. The `@synchronized` block around `self` says, implicitly: "I am going to moderate access to `self`, to make sure no one edits `self` while I'm looking at it, and also I will ensure that I grab the most up-to-date value of `self`'s instance variables, even across threads". This is how the delegate ensures that it has the latest `self.currentPreviewPixelBuffer`; if it was not `@synchronized`, you could get a stale copy.

   Also in the `@synchronized` block is the overwrite of `self.currentPreviewPixelBuffer`, after retaining it. This code implicitly says: "hey, if `self.currentPreviewPixelBuffer` is not `NULL`, then there must be a pixel buffer to process; if there is (line F), then I'll hold on to it (line E, G), and reset it on `self` (line H)". In effect, this takes ownership of `self`'s `currentPreviewPixelBuffer` so that no one else will process it. This is an implicit check for all delegate callback blocks operating on `self`: the first block to fire that looks at `self.currentPreviewPixelBuffer` gets to keep it, sets it to `NULL` for all other blocks looking at `self`, and does work with it. The others, having read `NULL` on line F, do nothing.
4. Lines I and J actually use the pixel buffer, and line K disposes of it properly.

It's true, this code could use some commenting -- it's really lines E through G that do a lot of the implicit work here, taking ownership of `self`'s preview buffer to keep others from processing the block as well. What the comment above line A does *not* say is, "Note that access to currentPreviewPixelBuffer is protected by `@synchronized`..., **in contrast to here where it's not; because it's not protected by that here, we can overwrite `self.currentPreviewPixelBuffer` as many times as we want before someone processes it, dropping the intermediate values**"

Hope that helps.

Comment: I think I am starting to grasp it now. Your explanation is amazing. I have to make a remark here to the way Apple write their documentations. I think 99.99% of everything Apple writes as documentation is pure garbage. Their sample code are too complex to explain basic things and poorly recommended. Their reference guides show how they hate developers and to write documentation. I am from the old school where documentations were master pieces of didactics and explanation. I am a book writer myself and I see how bad Apple docs are. If was not for SO we would be all doomed. Long live SO!

Comment: @SpaceDog Glad to have helped. FWIW, I don't think it's fair to say that Apple hates developers or documentation -- if that were the case, there wouldn't be any to speak of. We care very much about making our public-facing documentation as accessible as possible (and whether you think I'm biased or not, I do think we have some excellent documentation for our frameworks). I agree that some of the code examples can be difficult to get through, but keep in mind that it's code, not prose.

Comment: @SpaceDog It's impossible to put together a code sample without making decisions about minutae; in prose you can gloss over some details, but in code, it's not possible. This means that you either have to leave some decisions opaque (e.g. how does this drop frames?), or you have to leave tons of comments _everywhere_ to try to reach people of all skill levels. This can leave the code inundated with unrelated explanation and hard to read; it's difficult to strike an optimal balance. That's just the experience of delving into someone else's codebase; it's never easy, but we can fill in the gaps.

Comment: @SpaceDog In any case, if you think any code sample is unclear, file a bug about it. Feel free to link this SO question (or any others you have) in your report, and explain what you feel is missing -- it will get reviewed and fixed.

Comment: thanks but I will pass on that. I have filled almost 150 bug/feature/documentation reports in the past and no corrections were made. What I think is a piece of crap they may think is state-of-the-art and the thing remains as it is. Unfortunately filling anything is a waste of time in my opinion. They just fix what gives or may give them bad publicity, 99.99% of the time.

Answer (score 2):

OK, that's the interesting part:

```
// call under @synchronized( self )
- (void)outputPreviewPixelBuffer:(CVPixelBufferRef)previewPixelBuffer
{
    // Keep preview latency low by dropping stale frames that have not been picked up by the delegate yet
    // Note that access to currentPreviewPixelBuffer is protected by the @synchronized lock
    self.currentPreviewPixelBuffer = previewPixelBuffer;

    [self invokeDelegateCallbackAsync:^{

        CVPixelBufferRef currentPreviewPixelBuffer = NULL;
        @synchronized( self )
        {
            currentPreviewPixelBuffer = self.currentPreviewPixelBuffer;
            if ( currentPreviewPixelBuffer ) {
                CFRetain( currentPreviewPixelBuffer );
                self.currentPreviewPixelBuffer = NULL;
            }
        }

        if ( currentPreviewPixelBuffer ) {
            [_delegate capturePipeline:self previewPixelBufferReadyForDisplay:currentPreviewPixelBuffer];
            CFRelease( currentPreviewPixelBuffer );
        }
    }];
}
```

Basically what they do is use `currentPreviewPixelBuffer` property to track if the frame is stale.

If a frame is being processed for display (`invokeDelegateCallbackAsync:`) that property is set to `NULL` effectively discarding any enqueued frame (that would be waiting there for processing).

Note that this callback is being invoked asynchronously. Each captured frame calls `outputPreviewPixelBuffer:` and each displayed frame needs a call to `_delegate capturePipeline:previewPixelBufferReadyForDisplay:`.

Stale frames mean that `outputPreviewPixelBuffer` is called more often ('faster') that delegate can process them.
In such case however the property (which 'enqueues' next frame) will be set to `NULL` and callback will return immediately, leaving room for only the most recent frame.

Does it make sense to you?

**EDIT:**

Imagine following sequence of calls (very simplified):

TX = task X, FX = frame X

```
T1. output preview (F1)
T2. delegate callback start (F1)
T3. output preview (F2)
T4. output preview (F3)
T5. output preview (F4)
T6. output preview (F5)
T7. delegate callback stop (F1)
```

Callbacks for T3, T4, T5 and T6 wait on `@synchronized(self)` lock.

When T7 finishes what's the value of `self.currentPreviewPixelBuffer`?

It's F5.

We then run delegate callback for T3.

Do `self.currentPreviewPixelBuffer = NULL`

Delegate callback finishes.

We then run delegate callback for T4.

What's the value of `self.currentPreviewPixelBuffer`?

It's `NULL`.

So it's no-op.

Same for callbacks for T5 and T6.

Processed frames: F1 and F5. Dropped frames: F2, F3, F4.

Hope this helps

Comment: sorry, I am not seeing it. Lets consider the first line of the code `self.currentPreviewPixelBuffer = previewPixelBuffer;` at this line the property is set with `previewPixelBuffer` value and it is theoretically not nil. So, we have a valid buffer there. Then an asynchronous block runs and I don't see how this block detects stale frames. I see a @synchronized instruction there. I know what this instruction does in theoretical terms but I am also failing to understand in terms of the video frames coming, what this is exactly doing. Also, the first line of the code has also a similar comment

Comment: remember... explain it like I am 3 years old... 

Comment: this code makes no sense: `CVPixelBufferRef currentPreviewPixelBuffer = NULL;` is executed making it null. Then a @syncronize runs making the variable not null at the end an `if` asks if it is null. A completely insane code.

Comment: There are 2 references: `self.currentPreviewPixelBuffer` and `previewPixelBuffer`. You need 2 because the first one, property, is used to store incoming frames while the latter is used to pass a frame to delegate for display. Please note that these may reference different frames. Setting `previewPixelBuffer` to `NULL` basically means: 'I'm ready to start processing next frame`.

Comment: I agree with you, Apple often creates samples showing great features but the code is mind-numbingly complicated.

Comment: Grab a pen and paper and imagine `outputPreviewPixelBuffer:` takes 1 second to return and delegate callback takes 5 seconds to return. Run a small simulation on paper. Observe how these 2 references behave. You will notice that you are dropping frames. That's because you don't queue them.

Comment: Damn, I meant `currentPreviewPixelBuffer` not `previewPixelBuffer` in the first comment

Comment: Thanks for the effort but sorry, some stuff is not clear yet. I have added more info to the end of my question. Sorry bothering you but this theme appears to be interesting and I am not willing to give up easy!  please read the new info I have added.